# Alternatives to setting mouse position

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am currently trying to make an fps game in actionscript-3 (molehill). I have figured out how to do the rotation in accordance to the position of the mouse on the screen. The problem that i am having is that if i turn too much either way my mouse will go off the stage and i wont be turning anymore.

My original idea was to center the mouse position at the end of ever ENTER_FRAME event but after some searching found that was not possible.

Is there any alternate ways i could do this? I don't want to set a continuous rotation based on mouse position from the center because that can be very hard to control. Any contributions will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you're running in full screen mode on the desktop, you can use [Stage.mouseLock](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#mouseLock):

> Enabling mouse locking turns off the cursor, and allows mouse movement
>   with no bounds.